# FizzBuzz.cpp with lambdas?

Tags: c++, c++11, lambda

I'm trying to write FizzBuzz in C++11 using lambdas, but I'm getting a weird compiler error.

Code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
#include <list>
#include <algorithm>
using namespace std;

string fizzy(int n) {
  int a = n % 3, b = n % 5;

  if (a == 0 && b == 0) {
    return "FizzBuzz";
  }
  else if (a == 0) {
    return "Fizz";
  }
  else if (b == 0) {
    return "Buzz";
  }
  else {
    stringstream out;
    out << n;
    return out.str();
  }
}

void fizzbuzz() {
  string strings[100];
  list<int> range(0, 100);

  for_each(range.begin(), range.end(), [=](int i) {
      strings[i] = fizzy(i);
    });

  for_each(range.begin(), range.end(), [=](int i) {
      cout << strings[i] << endl;
    });
}

int main() { fizzbuzz(); }
```

Trace:

```
$ make
g++ -std=c++0x -o fizzy fizzy.cpp
fizzy.cpp: In lambda function:
fizzy.cpp:32:27: error: passing 'const std::string' as 'this' argument of 'std::basic_string<_CharT,
 _Traits, _Alloc>& std::basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _Alloc>::operator=(std::basic_string<_CharT, _
Traits, _Alloc>&&) [with _CharT = char, _Traits = std::char_traits<char>, _Alloc = std::allocator<ch
ar>, std::basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _Alloc> = std::basic_string<char>]' discards qualifiers
make: *** [fizzy] Error 1
```

Comment: `list<int> range(0, 100);` does *not* do what you think it does.

Comment: That has to be the most inefficient use of `for_each` ever.

Comment: Value captures are constant unless you make your lambda `mutable`.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You should **capture by reference** instead of capturing by value in your lambda:

```
for_each(range.begin(), range.end(), [&](int i) {
//                                    ^
    strings[i] = fizzy(i);
    });
```

That also happens to solve the problem - the call operator of a generated lambda closure is marked as `const` by default.

---

**NOTE:**

Another way to make this compile is to use the `mutable` keyword, as in the snippet below:

```
for_each(range.begin(), range.end(), [=](int i) mutable {
//                                              ^^^^^^^
    strings[i] = fizzy(i);
    });
```

The `mutable` keyword has the effect of dropping the `const` in the call operator of the generated lambda closure.

However, I do believe you really do *not* want this: why modifying strings in an array that you will forget about when the function returns?

Capturing by reference will solve your problem.

---

**UPDATE:**

As pointed out by Daniel Frey in the comments, this instruction:

```
list<int> range(0, 100);
```

Will create a list of size zero, whose elements (whose *zero* elements) are all initialized  with the value 100. Probably not what you want. You may want to change it into something like the following (`std::iota` is only available if you are working with C++11, otherwise you'll have to unroll your own loop of assignments):

```
#include <algorithm>

list<int> range(100); // Creates a list of 100 elements
iota(begin(range), end(range), 0); // Assigns value 0..99 to those elements
```

Comment: `mutable` alone won't fix the problem, `strings` is an array.

Comment: @Praetorian: It seems to compile [here](http://liveworkspace.org/code/yJL1f$27) though...

Comment: How on earth is an array copyable? Maybe the captured value is after the array to pointer implicit conversion? Also, from VS2012 *error C3478: 'strings' : an array cannot be captured by-value*. But all 2 compilers on LWS compile it.

Comment: @Praetorian: See 5.1.2/21: "When the lambda-expression is evaluated, the entities that are captured by copy are used to direct-initialize
each corresponding non-static data member of the resulting closure object. **(For array members, the array
elements are direct-initialized in increasing subscript order.)** [...]"

Comment: @AndyProwl: Capturing by reference is part of the solution, fixing `list<int> range( 0, 100 )` is the other one as with a range of zero `100`s, the output is quite limited :)

Comment: @DanielFrey: Oh, good catch, I haven't even noticed that one :)

Comment: Technically, you don't want to use mutable lambdas for this, as (stated in n3485 25.1p10) "algorithms that take function objects as arguments are permitted to copy those function objects freely."

Answer (score 1):

This change should fix it, so you capture by reference:

```
for_each(range.begin(), range.end(), [&strings](int i) {
  strings[i] = fizzy(i);
});
```

Also as Daniel and Andy point out your initialization of `range` is probably not what you expect since it creates a `zero` sized list:

```
list<int> range(0, 100);
```